# Do accessibility settings like 'aria-hidden' prevent Power Automate from clicking or pressing content on a web page?

Tags: accessibility, power-automate

I am trying to select a dynamic calendar on a website. My goal is to open the calendar and input dates as I need to. I am not able to open the calendar by "Press button on web page" or "Click link on web page" with my selected UI Element. There are no ID's available to select. I have tried using the div class names with no luck. I have tried altering the selector to make a custom selector that looks for div names containing part of the class name. The 'Name' attribute in Power Automate is unavailable for the UI Element.

After trying all this, I noticed an Icon that is part of a div for the calendar, has
aria-hidden="true"'. When I checked the MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-hidden) it has a warning statement: "Warning: Do not use aria-hidden="true" on focusable elements."

With being unable to select the calendar with standard and custom selectors, am I being blocked by the accessibility setting? Is Power Automate unable to focus on the calendar opener from aria-hidden="true"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know power automate, but what you observe makes sense. The attribute aria-hidden=true tells assistive tools such as screen readers and voice control software to ignore the element, as if it wasn't present at all.

A focusable element **must never be aria-hidden=true**. A screen reader won't know what to say when landing on it, and, as observed, it won't be reachable using voice control.
That's simply a pure accessibility fail (I would even call it stupidity, but well).

Technically, the solution is very simple: remove that stupid offending aria-hidden=true. Those who made that calendar probably put it there because:

- they thought that screen reader and voice control users will always enter a date by hand and won't ever use the date picker
- the date picker hasn't been made accessible, and so it's better to ignore it completely rather to present something only partially accessible
- They copy/paste the code from elsewhere and didn't pay attention

They have no excuse for the third one, and for the two first, both reasoning are just wrong. Even if it isn't perfect, it's better to have a little something rather than nothing.
Keyboard-only user or screen reader user don't necessarily mean eased to enter a date manually. ON a mobile, the virtual keyboard is often painful to use, and people with limited movement sometimes use a device with only a few available keys (such as enter, tab, escape, and arrow keys only). Additionally, both might be combined if you think about someone who has a strong dyslexia and an inability to use his hands (the device would be actioned with feet, blinking eyes, etc.).

In theory, you shouldn't ever use custom widgets if you can avoid it. For entering dates, the standard exists: input type=date and friends.
Using standard widgets is the best guaranty to have something accessible at long term. Even if it might not be 100% accessible right now, it's getting better as the time passes.
Sadly, UX designers often don't like standard widgets much because it doesn't look like what they want, and there are still a few older browsers which don't support them all very well.